# cardinality of set $S_A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $S_A$ be a set such that

> $$S_A=\left\{ A_{6 \times 6}|A^2=A\right\}$$
>   if Any two matrices $A$ and $B$ $\in S_A$ such that $\nexists$ $P$ such $P^{-1}AP=B$
>
> Then the number of elements in $S_A$ is ?

$\textbf{solution I tried}$-The given set of matrices is a set of idempotent matrices.Then from condition he is giving hint that given set of matrices is a set of non-similar matrices but within the set.but from this data how can I find cardinality of $S_A$ ?

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Hint: If $J$ is the Jordan normal form of $A$, then $J^2=J$ iff $A^2=A$ (why?). What does an idempotent matrix look like in Jordan normal form?

Comment: because $A^2=A$ has minimal polynomial $x(x-1)$?

Comment: What is $A_{6\times 6}$ and what is $A$?

Comment: a matrix of 6 by 6 order

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Let $S_A$ be a set such that 
$S_A=\left\{ A_{6 \times 6}|A^2=A\right\}$".  $S_A=\left\{ A_{6 \times 6}|A^2=A\right\}$ means that $S_A$ is the set of all matrices satisfying $A^2 = A$.  However, this is clearly not what you're trying to say since the question implies that $S_A$ should also be such that for any $A,B \in S_A$, there is no $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP = B$.

Comment: @TheStudent Look at the answer given by me and state what difficulties arises with this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $7$. To prove this I will use Jardon Canonical form of matrices and the statement that two matrices are similar if and only if their Jardon canonical form are same. So in this way our problem is reduced to find distinct number of possible Jardon form $6\times 6$ idempotent matrices.

Since eigen values of $A$ are either $0$ or $1$ and we know that all idempotent matrices are diagnolizable. Therefore number of distinct Jardon form of idempotent matrices is number of ways of its characteristic, since minimal polynomial has only linear factors. First if all  eigen values are $0$ then it is similar to zero matrix and if all  eigen values are $1$ then it is similar to identity matrix. Now suppose it has both eigen values $0$ and $1$. Then its characterstic polynomial is $x^m(x-1)^n$ such that $n+m=6, n\neq 0, m\neq 0.$ Now we have total $5$ choices for the pair $(n,m)$ are $(1,5),(2,4),(3,3),(5,1),(2,4)$. Using Jordan canonical form it can be seen that all these are different upto similarity. Therefore carinality of $S_A$ is $7$.

Comment: Thankyou @MANI for your answer,,but how did your answer satisfies my questions conditions?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are said to be similar if there exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP=B$. Therefore your problem is nothing but to find number of non similar $6\times 6$ idempotent matrices. No you can easily see in my answer every condition is fulfilled. Do you know the result I have mentioned in beginning of my proof? If not then it is very tough to solve your problem , because we mustneed this to solve  the problem.

Comment: now i got this.

Comment: @TheStudent If my answer is sufficient please mark it.